# Django Rest Framework registrations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have a custom user model

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    username = None    
    email = models.EmailField( unique=True)    
    phone = models.CharField( max_length=15) 
    is_pro = models.BooleanField(default=False)    

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone']

    objects = UserManager()

    @property
    def token(self):
    """
    Allows us to get a user's token by calling `user.token` instead of
        `user.generate_jwt_token().

    The `@property` decorator above makes this possible. `token` is called
    a "dynamic property".
    """
        return self._generate_jwt_token()

    def _generate_jwt_token(self):
        """
        Generates a JSON Web Token that stores this user's ID and has an expiry
        date set to 60 days into the future.
        """
        import jwt
        from datetime import datetime, timedelta
        from django.conf import settings
        dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)

        token = jwt.encode({
            'id': self.pk,
            'exp': int(dt.strftime('%s'))
        }, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')

        return token.decode('utf-8')
```

Now I try make SignIn API with Django Rest Framework using this tutorial https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/authentication

**serializer.py**

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True
    )


    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = ['email', 'phone', 'password', 'token']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Use the `create_user` method we wrote earlier to create a new user.
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

**views.py**

```
class RegistrationAPIView(APIView):
    # Allow any user (authenticated or not) to hit this endpoint.
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)    
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data.get('user', {})

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Then I create a new user an error occured "This field is required." for all my User fields, like email, phone, password.
Screenshot picture http://joxi.ru/12MOMkZt4eeBEr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set this fields not nullable and required inside `User` model. To fix it you can add [`blank=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#blank) arguments to the fields which may be blank, like `phone`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    username = None    
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)    
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True) 
    is_pro = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

After this run `makemigrations` and `migrate` to apply changes at DB level.

**UPD**

In view you need to get data from `request.data` directly:

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

`request.data` doesn't contain `user` key, so `request.data.get('user', {})` return empty dict.

Comment: I maked phone ( blank=True) and now same error occured fields email and password http://joxi.ru/J2bR7ZDC4ddP72. Is it right way make all fields blank = True?

Comment: @lepiloff I suppose `email` and `password` fields are required for registration process. So it's not good Idea to add `blank=True` for this two fields. You just need to enter some data here to register new user.

Comment: The problem is that the error appears after I enter the data of the user and press the POST button