# django rest registration api error: this field is required

Tags: django, rest, api, frameworks, registration

Hello i want to create a simple registration api for my django rest api
But when i want to test the registration with curl i get always get this error:
{"username":["This field is required."],"password":["This field is required."]}

This is my curl cmd:

```python
curl --request POST --url http://localhost:8000/auth/register/ --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"username": "user1","password": "hunter2"}'
```

views.py RegistrationApi

```python
class RegistrationAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        })
```

serializers.py

```python
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'],
                                        None,
                                        validated_data['password'])
        return user


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')
```

Maybe there is something wrong with the serializers? I already tried so figure out where the problem is but i cant find it

Comment: Probably you overrided default parsers? Check this http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password' : {'write_only': True}}
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

**Or refer to link** [Django Rest Framework registrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997983/django-rest-framework-registrations)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! You can explain me the reason why my code does not work?

Comment: Brother, Create_user parameter already takes username and password using BaseUserManger in models so you don't need to ask for those again, instead just pass the data in create_user and then its validated and stored. voila!